# How can I show div(s) by selected option?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a select list which contains the number of guests for a room I need to hold, the code is:

```
<select name="txtHotelGuestNO" id="txtHotelGuestNO" class="hotels" onchange="show_room_choose()">
    <? for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) echo "<option value=$i>$i</option>"; ?>
    </select>
```

If I select 2 people I need to only show the divs with the ids *single* and *double* like this:

```
    <div id="single"> ... code</div>
<div id="double">... code</div>
```

If I select more than 2 we need to show **all** room type div.

If I select 1 person I need to only show the div for **single**.

How can I do this using ajax?

Comment: Unless you're fetching the room data from the server AFTER the user makes a choice, AJAX is not the right tool for the job, JavaScript it.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need AJAX. AJAX is for retrieving or sending data to a server. Since you appear to have all the information you need on the page already (the select and the two divs you want to show or hide), you shouldn't need AJAX - is that accurate to say it's all already on the page? Or is there something missing from your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jQuery:

```
// Wait for DOM to be ready (if you are including the JavaScript before the HTML, ie the <head>)
$(document).ready(function()) {
    // listen for when the user changes the value in the <select> dropdown
    $('#txtHotelGuestNO').change(function() {

        // get value selected
        var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);  // parseInt() converts the value to integer (base 10)

        if (value < 2) {
            // single
            $('#single').show();
            $('#double').hide();
        } else {
            // double
            $('#double').show()
            $('#single').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can learn more about the jQuery methods used:

- `.change()`: http://api.jquery.com/change/
- `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val/
- `.show()`: http://api.jquery.com/show/
- `.hide()`: http://api.jquery.com/hide
- `.ready()`: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Set both divs to display:none and send the value of the selection to your onchange function:

```
function show_room_choose(value) {
     if(value==1) { 
          document.getElementById("single").style.display = "block"; 
          document.getElementById("double").style.display = "none";
     } else if(value==2) { 
          document.getElementById("single").style.display = "block"; 
          document.getElementById("double").style.display = "block";
     } else  { 
          document.getElementById("single").style.display = "block"; 
          document.getElementById("double").style.display = "block";
          // add whatever other divs to show here
     }
}
```